# PDOException: in C:\wamp64\www\Fireblock\index.php on line 3

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

Help i wanna make a register system but when i try to access the page on localhost it say me this :

Fatal error: in C:\wamp64\www\Fireblock\index.php on line 3
PDOException: in C:\wamp64\www\Fireblock\index.php on line 3

Idk what's wrong in line 3 since i was following a tutorial oof

My php script :

```
<?php

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fireblock;', 'root', ''); //where is the error
    
    if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $email    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $email2   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email2']);
        $pass     = password_hash($_POST['password']);
        $pass2    = password_hash($_POST['password2']);
        
        if (!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['password']) AND !empty($_POST['password2'])) {
            $usernamelength = strlen($username);
            if ($usernamelength <= 255) {
                if ($email == $email2) {
                    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        if ($password == $password2) {
                            $insertmember = $bdd->prepare("INSERT into members(username, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
                            $insertmember->execute(array(
                                $username,
                                $email,
                                $password
                            ));
                            $error = "Your account has been created!";
                        } else {
                            $error = "Your passwords aren't the same!";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $error = "Your email address isn't valid!";
                    }
                } else {
                    $error = "Your emails aren't the same!";
                }
            } else {
                $error = "Your username can't be higher than 255 characters!";
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Every fields should be completed!";
        }
    }
    
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    print $ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I putted all the PHP part

Comment: you need to put some code in the question, we don't want the entire script just the section that's causing the error and any relevant info.  Also there's part of the error missing i think, usually there's a bit more info

Comment: nah it only told me this on the webpage btw let me edit it

Comment: @aZermyux Can you put `try catch` block to get detailed stacktrace? `catch(PDOException $ex){ print $ex->getMessage() }`

Comment: where @HansanaAthukorala

Comment: @aZermyux To your code?

Comment: yes but where in the code

Comment: Put your above code inside `try` block and `catch` block should be what I sent above in comments

Comment: where is the try block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223915/discussion-between-hansana-athukorala-and-azermyux).

Comment: hello, sorry but right now i found the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fireblock', 'root', '');
```

i have removed a semi-colon at the end of the last key/value pair (after fireblock) as it is not used in any code examples i used for comparrison with your code.